# Remove ^@ character from a string

Tags: regex, perl, csv, utf-8

I have the following problem. I have a CSV file that comes from an external source, and I'm trying to read it using the [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module in the following way

```
$csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1}) or die "Could not open $filename : ".Text::CSV->error_diag();

binmode("stdout", ":utf8");

open $fh, "<encoding(utf8)", $filename or die "Could not open $filename : $!\n";

while ($row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $#{$row}; $i++) {
        $data = encode("utf8", $row->[$i]);
        print "$data\n";
    }
    print "$row->[$keycol] => $row->[$valcol]\n";
    $hash{$row->[$keycol]} = $row->[$valcol];
}

$csv->eof() or die " Error--- $i ".($csv->error_diag())."\n";
```

However, the program dies with an error after reading in a few lines from that file.

On inspection I found out that there are columns in the data which are supposed to be enclosed in quotes `" ... "` but only one of the quotes is there. Instead of a matching quote there is this odd `^@` character there. How do I replace all those `^@` characters with quotes? It isn't simple ASCII so I can't do `$str =~ s/\^\@/\"/g`.

Comment: What is `$keycol`? It isn't defined in the code that you show.

Comment: You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program that you write, and declare all of your variables using `my` as close as possible to their first point of use.

Comment: You say, *“the program dies with an error”*. What is the error message, please? What are you using to see the `^@` character? It is most likely to indicate the NUL character with a code point of zero. Where does your input data originate? I think you should be very careful with the data if it truly has mismatched quotation marks: it is highly likely that there are other problems as well that you haven't noticed.

Comment: Control-@ is also known as the null byte, `'\0'`, which is used to terminate strings.  This is based on the ASCII value of `@` (64), compared with the ASCII value of `A` (65), and `^A` (control-A) is `'\1`, so `^@` is `'\0'`.  That leaves you with potential problems when wrangling the data as a string — the `^@` marks the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks all for the pointers. This indeed does look like a data problem that is best fixed from the sender of the data, doesn't seem like there is anything to be done from a receivers point of view.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Perl doesn't use `'\0'` to mark the end of a string. ` $s = "foo\0bar\0baz"; $s =~ s/\0/Z/; print "$s\n";` --> `fooZbarZbaz`

Answer (score 0):

`^@` conventionally represents `NUL` (ASCII `00`). In Perl double-quoted and regex literals, it can be represented by `\c@`, `\0`, `\x00`, etc

```
$str =~ s/\c@/"/g;
```

When most people try to remove NULs, it's because they have undecoded UTF-16. The solution is actually to perform proper decoding and encoding. It's unclear if that's the problem you are facing.

Answer (score -1):

I strongly recommend you go to the person you got this file from and ask them for a copy of it that they didn't edit in MS Word or whatever it was.  It sounds rather like you're describing a file that has been savaged by a word processor that believes in a more decorative form of quotation mark set, and it's replacing one of them with the "upside down" version of a quotation mark. i.e., "smart quotes".

If the editor did this to the double-quotes, there's likely to be more damaged data in there as well.   In theory you might be able to revert them with  **s/\x93/"/g** and **s/\x94/"/g** but certainly they should *never be in a CSV-formatted file in the first place.*

Comment: ...and this was downvoted _why_ precisely?  Those two regexps should convert any funky "smartquotes" back into sane and reasonable quotes (i.e., \0x22, aka ASCII 34) in short order as a triage step.  Editors that do that sort of thing are known to also mangle ellipses and the minus sign (as well as several other characters) and are not friendly to data processing.